# IIS 7 Configure multiple application on a site with different framework target

Tags: iis-7

Is it possible to configure multiple applications with different .net framework on IIS 7?

I want to configure a website like:

- mysite.com(.net framework 4, App pool 4)
- mysite.com/app1 (.net framework 2, app pool 2)
- mysite.com/app2 (.net framework 2,app pool 2)
- mysite.com/app3 (.net framework 2,app pool 2)
- mysite.com/app4 (.net framework 2,app pool 2)

I tried like above and mysite.com works well, mysite.com/app1 is getting config error,

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Any idea how to keep this structure?

Comment: Yes it is possible. The error indicates that the Web.config has configuration settings not supported by asp.net 2. Please post your config file if you can.

Comment: <b> compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" </b> When i acces "mysite.com/app1" it is referring parent folders config, how can i escape that?

Comment: Thank you,  I guess the issue is like below.. let me try more this way : http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/04/solved-iis7-validateintegratedmodeconfi.html

Comment: @BernieWhite - You're right, the 2.0 app pool does not recognize the attribute, but his question was "how do I keep this structure"? Meaning, what is the proper way to run 2.0 applications with 2.0 app pools on a Site that uses a 4.0 target framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting "inheritInChildApplications=false" on web.config solved my issue.

He is the details:
http://runtingsproper.blogspot.jp/2010/04/solved-iis7-validateintegratedmodeconfi.html

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the application pool targeting the wrong .net framework, change the application pool to the correct .net framework and the error will be resolved

Comment: No, Im pretty sure i have configured proper pools,

Comment: I had the same problem but using VS’ virtual server not IIS.
So here an article that could help you if you have the same problem:http://extremedev.blogspot.com/2011/10/migrating-wdproj-from-vs-2008-to-vs.html let me know

Comment: All thanks, for your feedback, i guess my issue is relates something like this    http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/04/solved-iis7-validateintegratedmodeconfi.html